# ¿Cómo usar recursividad en estos ejemplos de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hace poco empecé a ver el tema de recursividad, pero por mas que lo intento no consigo verlo claramente. Tengo un par de ejercicios en los que se me pide que; en uno obtenga una palabra del revés, y en el otro tengo que buscar el índice de un elemento en un array. Esto es lo que tengo.
En este ejercicio en concreto se me dan ya los dos parámetros.

```
function reverseSent(sentence, position){
  let reverseFinal = "";
  for(position of sentence){
     reverseFinal = position + reverseFinal;
  }
  return reverseFinal; 
}
console.log(reverseSent("hello"));
```

El segundo es el siguiente:

```
datArray = ["java", "html", "javascript", "css"];

function findIndex(datArray, element){
   for(let index = 0; index < datArray.length; index++){
      if(datArray[index] === element) return index;
}
  return -1;
}
console.log("Index position is: " + findIndex(datArray, 'html'));
```

En ambos casos el código funciona pero se me pide hacerlo recursivamente.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: Deberías agregar lo que has intentado hacer. Esto que pides es hacerte la tarea.

Comment: @Lobos por si no has leido, eso es lo que yo he intentado, ambos codigos los hice yo pero no de forma recursiva claro esta porque no sabia como hacerlo. Gracias por tu aportacion = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda función recursiva debe tener al menos una condición (un if) de parada, para que evitar que siga hasta el infinito (puede tener más de una condición de parada). Entonces deben existir al menos 2 `return` uno que devuelve un valor y otro que devuelve la misma función

Sobre tus casos, empezaré por el segundo

**1.- Retornar el índice**

Cuando haces muchas funciones recursivas, eventualmente te darás cuenta que en realidad muchas formas se repiten. Este es un caso típico de transformar un `for` en función recursiva, para ello hay que pasar el `índice` como argumento y además tendremos 2 condiciones de parada:

- Cuando encontramos el elemento
- Cuando el índice supera la el largo del array

```js
datArray = ["java", "html", "javascript", "css"];

function findIndex(datArray, element,indice=0) {
  if(indice >= datArray.length) return -1;
  else if(datArray[indice] === element) return indice;
  return findIndex(datArray,element,indice + 1);
}
console.log("Index position is: " + findIndex(datArray, 'html'));
```

**2.- Invertir palabra**

Para invertir una palabra puedes usar el siguiente algoritmo:

```js
function Invertir(palabra){
  let result="";
  for(let i=0; i<palabra.length; i++){
    result+=palabra[palabra.length-1-i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(Invertir("Hola Mundo"));
```

Con esto volvemos a tener el caso de convertir un `for` a recursivo, y aplicamos lo mismo que lo anterior, pero ahora como NO estamos buscando "algo" solo necesitamos una condición de parada.

```js
function Invertir(palabra,indice=0){
  if(indice >=palabra.length) return "";
  return palabra[palabra.length-1-indice] + Invertir(palabra,indice+1);
}

console.log(Invertir("Hola Mundo"));
```

Como te habrás dado cuenta, se retorna el valor + la función recursiva, está es la manera de retornar la acumulación (suple lo que en el ejemplo anterior es la variable `let result=""` que guarda el acumulado).

Pero no vayas a pensar que la única manera de recursión es ir pasando el índice, solo es la manera fácil, también puedes hacer algo como esto.

Que es ir tomando la ultima_letra + la función recursiva del resto de la plabra:

```js
function Invertir(palabra) {
  if(palabra.length==0) return "";
  return palabra.slice(-1) + Invertir(palabra.substring(0,palabra.length-1));
}

console.log(Invertir("Hola Mundo"));
```

Este último caso también es típico, vamos pasando una colección (array, pila, cola o en este caso un string que es una colección de letras) y cada vez que lo volvemos a pasar por la recursión le quitamos un elemento, hasta que eventualmente queda vacío.

Comment: Hola @Yussef, en la llamada a **findIndex** del primer ejemplo, se te trastabillaron los dedos, podrías corregirla?.

Comment: @MarcePuente como?

Comment: es solo un error de tipeo, cambia  **findIndex(datArray, 'htmsl')** por **findIndex(datArray, 'html, 0')**.

Comment: @MarcePuente Ok, gracias por el aviso

Comment: gracias a ti que siempre me estás enseñando!! (a mi y a muchos).

Comment: @Yussef  muchisimas gracias por la explicacion.

Answer (score 2):

A la hora de pensar en funciones recursivas, hay que imaginarse que esa función ya existe y que funciona correctamente. Entonces, creas una función con el mismo nombre y las mismas entradas y salidas, que resuelva solo el primer caso, y usas "la otra función" para solucionar el resto del problema. En caso de no existir ese "primer caso" (o que "la otra función" retorne algún error), sales retornando un valor adecuado al problema.
Para que "la otra función" resuelva el resto, se debe poder indicar cual es el "resto", con un contador, índice, rango...
Por ejemplo:

```js
function invertirTexto (texto,contador){
  if (!contador) contador = 1;
  if (contador > texto.length) return '';
  return texto[texto.length-contador]+invertirTexto(texto, contador+1);
}
console.log(invertirTexto("Buenas tardes."));
```